# Is there a way in the Delphi XE2 IDE to find last changes to a line in SVN?

Tags: delphi, svn, delphi-xe2

There was one feature in Visual Source Safe (at least the Delphi 7 [visual source safe connector](http://www.epocalipse.com/vcx.htm)) that was really handy that we miss quite a bit since changing over to SVN and Delphi XE2.

It was a feature that allowed you to right click on a line of code and see the last changes to it.

Is there any way to replicate this with Delphi's SVN integration?

---

If not, could someone point me in the right direction on how to write a Delphi Add-on module to accomplish this with Tortoise SVN? (I don't particularly care for the built-in integration anyway) I think it'd be pretty good project, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: svn blame is the closest you'll get to this I guess. Tortoise has a blame UI.